# I have "Roach Motel Data" - data go into DB fine, cannot get back out

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms with EF and SqLite.  I've installed the "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Nuget package in my project.  The code issue is in the shared code project, .NetStandard 2.0.

- I have created a simple class, let's say CAT class to hold my DB table objects
- I can use the "ensurecreated" command and that works fine
- I can create a CAT, set properties and SaveChanges() to the DB; this works fine, I can see the data in the DB
- I cannot get the data back out; I get an "object not set to a reference..." error.

Ignore my couple of outer curly braces; new to posting code and only way to get it all together in one block.  I have handled the platform-specific (Android & iOS) code for obtaining the dbPath to the SqLite .db3 file (not shown here).

Cannot figure what I'm missing that no data will come back out of DB.  Any help much appreciated!

```
    {
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        string _dbPath;

        public DbSet<Cat> Cats { get; set; }

        public DatabaseContext(string dbPath)
        {
            _dbPath = dbPath;

            Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Cat>> GetCats()
        {
            var allCats = await Cats.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            return allCats;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={_dbPath}");
        }
    }


    List<Cat> itemSource;

    // Create Database & Tables
    using (var db = new DatabaseContext(App.dbPath))
    {
        // Ensure database is created
        db.Database.EnsureCreated();

        // Insert Data
        db.Add(new Cat() { IdCat = "111", Fname = "Felix1" });
        db.SaveChanges();

        // Retreive Data

        //method 1
        // RESULT:  no data are in "itemsource", info reads "exception count = 1"
        itemSource = db.Cats.ToList();

        // method 2
        // RESULTS:  crashes with error "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
        Task<IEnumerable<Cat>> p = db.GetCats();    

        itemSource = db.Cats.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try examples from this resource:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/124606/need-code-sample-for-xamarin-forms-using-entity-framework-core-2-0-with-migration-support

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those out too.  However, I've been through 6-8 examples elsewhere and what I'd really like to know is whether this code is right, and if so, why the error?  What about this code is incorrect approach to using EF with SqLite in Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: sorry, can't help you in it because I haven't used EF for my work. I've used 'sqlite-net-pcl' for my purposes.
Maybe you could try to use async awaitable calls of `SaveChanges()` and `Add()`.

Comment: I'd start by removing all async code. Start with the simplest thing to eliminate possible issues. There are a number of variables there, async, sqlLite, .ConfigureAsync... Start basic, see if that works, then gradually add details for the desired behaviour and see where it breaks.

Comment: which specific line of code is causing the exception?

Comment: I noted the last two lines (i.e. "RESULTS"), see the two methods of retrieving data.

Comment: I wonder if there are any further thoughts having pointed out the line which causes the exception?  Also, with the "microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlite" nuget package, there seems to be no options for "non-async" calls.  Everything seems to be async.  Is it possible you see the non-async in the other sqlite nuget package, "sqlite-net-pcl"?  I'm not using that one.

Comment: Hello again. I've gotten past this error. I can't swear its exact cause, but it likely relates to the dbContext and the way I was structuring things.

So now I have a follow-up question... right now I'm establishing a public static dbContext variable in the app.cs. I was going to then use that throughout the program.

    does that work, and
    is that approach "bad practice" or "commonly done" ?  Also, with EF should I be using a repository?

Comment: UPDATE:  Still need help, but I've more information...

Comment: Answered! See [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655132/how-can-i-query-sqlite-in-xamarin-using-entity-framework)

Comment: Please post your answer, It will help others who have similar issue.