# How can I query Sqlite in Xamarin using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-6

I'm in a Xamarin.Forms project (C#) using Sqlite and EF plug-in (Microsoft.Enttityframeworkcore.sqlite). What happens depends:

Scenario 1: I use "Database.EnsureDeletedAsync"

- I can put data into DB
- within the same "using" statement and "dbContext" object, I can retrieve the data using LINQ query no errors.

Scenario 2: I do not use "Database.EnsureDeletedAsync"

- the database already exists
- I can add data to it
- within the same "using" statement and "dbContext" object, any attempt to retrieve the data using LINQ query (I've tried multiple
  ways), results in error (System.NullReferenceException: Object
  reference not set to an instance of an object).

In BOTH scenarios, I am able to ADB pull the db from the Android emulator and verify

1) the db exists and 
2) my data are going into it.

FYI - the DbPath is verified to be correct (again, I can pull the DB and see data in it).

```
// POCO class

public class Participant
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Fname { get; set; }
}


// DB Context

public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
        string _dbPath;

        public DbSet<Participant> Participants { get; set; }

        public DatabaseContext(string dbPath)
        {
            _dbPath = dbPath;

            //Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();
            //Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={_dbPath}");
        }
}


// Main page code-behind

InitializeComponent ();

// Create Database & Tables
using (var db = new DatabaseContext(App.DbPath))
{
    // Insert Data
    db.Add(new Participant() { Fname = "time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() });
    db.SaveChanges();

    // Retrieve Data
    // Next two lines receive error in scenario 2
    var result2 = db.Participants.Where(xyz => xyz.Id == 1).ToList();
    IEnumerable<Participant> p = db.Participants.ToList();
}
```

Comment: you need to identify which specific part of the statement is causing the null ref.

Comment: I did.  It's in the code area, near bottom.

Comment: Not the line of code, which part of the statement is null.    Is it Participants?  Or the Where clause?  Or something else?  Then figure out Why it’s null.

Comment: Ok, so I've broken the "result2" line into two lines.  The exception is being thrown on the second line.  I can mouse-over and see that 1) the db has the table in it, and 2) the participants doesn't fail, but it appears to have no items in it:

Comment: var result2 = db.Participants;   <--- DOES NOT CRASH
var result3 = db.Participants.Where(xyz => xyz.Id == 1).ToList();  <--- CRASHES WITH ERROR

Answer (score 0):

I add `db.Database.EnsureCreated();` before you update data:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //iOS
    var dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "..", "Library", "iOSTest.db");

    // Android
    var dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "AndroidTest.db");



    // Create Database & Tables
    using (var db = new DatabaseContext(dbPath))
    {

        db.Database.EnsureCreated();

        // Insert Data
        db.Add(new Participant() { Fname = "time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() });
        db.SaveChanges();

        // Retrieve Data
        // Next two lines receive error in scenario 2
        var result2 = db.Participants.Where(xyz => xyz.Id == 1).ToList();
        IEnumerable<Participant> p = db.Participants.ToList();
    }
}
```

And DB Context:

```
  // DB Context

    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        string _dbPath;

        public DbSet<Participant> Participants { get; set; }

        public DatabaseContext(string dbPath)
        {
            _dbPath = dbPath;

        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={_dbPath}");
        }
    }
```

1.You can try to change the DB name in your project to check if there is any wrong data in the old db.
2.Problems may caused by the asynchronous method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried adding the "db.Database.EnsureCreated();" line just prior to the "db.Add..." lines, but received the same error.  The same thing happened when I just called the ensurecreated method within the dbContext file.  It's only when I DELETE (ensuredeleted) in the same run as ensurecreated, add data and then retrieve it in the same run that things work.

Comment: @Donna So, the problem is participants has no item in it.  Since you can pull the DB and see data, can you see the data in the table with Id  = 1? Are  you using the same code as mine, any additional code? You can create a new project and use my code, it works on my side. And did you give your db a new name to test?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!  It turned out to be the dbContext and how/where that was defined vs. where it was attempted to be used.  Code has been restructured to ensure not to lose the context scope before performing reads and writes.